# New jenkins version, builds failing when I use build-flow, lack build history

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-build-flow

I just upgraded the jenkins to 2.164, Here is the error message I'm getting at the end of all the jobs.
I'm using build flow, I know that I must add entries to whitelisted-classes.txt, but

First log

> ERROR: Step ‘Use publishers from another project’ aborted due to
>   exception:  java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Refusing to
>   marshal java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock for security reasons;
>   see https://jenkins.io/redirect/class-filter/     at
>   hudson.util.XStream2$BlacklistedTypesConverter.marshal(XStream2.java:546)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:69)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:58)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller$1.convertAnother(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:84)
>     at
>   hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.marshallField(RobustReflectionConverter.java:265)
>     at
>   hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter$2.writeField(RobustReflectionConverter.java:252)

when I add startup jenkins command

```
-Dhudson.remoting.ClassFilter=java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock
```

then I'm getting this message

> ERROR: Step ‘Use publishers from another project’ aborted due to
>   exception:  java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Refusing to
>   marshal java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync for
>   security reasons; see https://jenkins.io/redirect/class-filter/   at
>   hudson.util.XStream2$BlacklistedTypesConverter.marshal(XStream2.java:546)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:69)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:58)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller$1.convertAnother(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:84)
>     at
>   hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.marshallField(RobustReflectionConverter.java:265)
>     at
>   hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter$2.writeField(RobustReflectionConverter.java:252)

And I try add next entries jenkins command
e.g
 -`Dhudson.remoting.ClassFilter=java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock,java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync`

but still returns an error

> ERROR: Step ‘Use publishers from another project’ aborted due to
>   exception:  java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Refusing to
>   marshal java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync for
>   security reasons; see https://jenkins.io/redirect/class-filter

but, when jenkins start I see -`Dhudson.remoting.ClassFilter=java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock,java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock`

does not return the phrase after `"$NonfairSync"`, Why ? What I can do wrong ?

Next answer, what can I change startup file in jenkins gui ?? (script console, but which command I can use it ?)